# retrieving data with reference to value of the variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

```
- !ruby/object:Pacdoc
    attributes:
    id: 5
    pac_id: 5
    doc_id: 1
    created_at: 2013-06-26 12:07:33.263881000 Z
    updated_at: 2013-06-26 12:07:33.263881000 Z

- !ruby/object:Pacdoc
    attributes:
    id: 6
    pac_id: 5
    doc_id: 2
    created_at: 2013-06-26 12:07:33.266881000 Z
    updated_at: 2013-06-26 12:07:33.266881000 Z
```

have collected the above data in a variable **@pdocs** and was able to single out the value of **doc_id**

```
<%= @pdocs.each do |a| %>
   <%= b = a.doc_id %>
<% end%>
```

now want to retrive the data from the table **'doc' with structure doc_id, name:string** below are models

```
models
class Pacdoc < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :doc_id, :pac_id

  belongs_to :pac
  belongs_to :doc
end

class Pac < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name

  validates :name, :presence => :true

  has_many :pacdocs
  has_many :docs, :through => :pacdocs
end

class Doc < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name

  validates :name, :presence => :true

  has_many :pacdocs
  has_many :pacs, :through => :pacdocs
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand what you want, but I guess you want to retrieve data from the `Doc` model where the foreign key in `Pacdoc` matches. You actually don't need to match the IDs manually, ActiveRecord handles that for you. To retrieve the name of the `Doc` you would just do:

```
<%= @pdocs.each do |a| %>
   <%= a.doc.name %>
<% end%>
```

Although when doing this, beware of N+1 queries.

Comment: thank you mario,this works just what i wanted, can you pl suggest how to overcome the constraint (N + 1 queries)

Comment: The problem with N+1 queries is rather simple. I suggest you just read the following part of the Rails guide. It explains what N+1 queries are and how to avoid them. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations